# SharePoint 2010 Workflows

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, workflow, sharepoint-workflow

What is the difference between Publishing Approval and Approval - SharePoint 2010 Workflows in SharePoint 2010?

We have Pages library and need to setup the versioning for the pages created newly or modified pages.

Answer (score 0):

The regular Approval workflow and the Publishing Approval workflow both route content to an individual or group of people for approval in the same way.

The difference comes in that you would normally use the Publishing Approval workflow for sites that you require content tracking and version control. You can only use Publishing Approval when the Publishing feature is enabled. This means stricter control is used before items are added (published) or deleted.

The Publishing Approval workflow association and initiation forms hide the option to add approvers, end workflow on first rejection, end workflow if document changes, and enable content approval inorder to achieve this stricter control.

As per : https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Understand-approval-workflows-in-SharePoint-2010-a24bcd14-0e3c-4449-b936-267d6c478579?CorrelationId=a9b928d6-afea-4ff0-9fb4-1475270cf32e&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US